# How do Java arrays process?

Tags: java, arrays

First, a summary: I'm working through some elementary problems on CodingBat.com (good stuff for beginners or the rusty like me) and decided to loop through arrays the "new" way.

I said I was "rusty".

**This works:**

```
public int arrayCount9(int[] nums) {
  int b=0;
  for(int i=0; i<nums.length;i++){
    if(nums[i]==9) b++;
  }
  return b;
}
```

**This does not work:**

```
public int arrayCount9(int[] nums) {
  int b=0;
   for(int i: nums){
     if(nums[i]==9) b++;
   }
  return b;
}
```

The error: Exception:java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9 (line number:4)

**So the issue is if(nums[i]==9) b++; **

So my questions are:

**1)** **What is the issue?**

**2)** **Does anyone have a spec reference?**

In regards to #2, I've tried googling, but haven't found what I'm looking for, and even with tutorials I haven't been able to quite grasp the voodoo underneath.

I thank you in advance.

edit  [link to problem in question](http://codingbat.com/prob/p184031)

Comment: In your first example `i` is index, but in second `i` is value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this part of the spec:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#d5e17093

It will explain it all. The enhanced for loop will return the values from the iterator immediately so your 'i' is actually the array value not the index.

Answer (score 4):

You use the iterated values as indexes. It should be:

```
for(int i: nums){
    if(i==9) b++;
}
```

So if you have a value bigger than the array size in the array, you get an index out of bounds exception.

Answer (score 4):

You are confused about how a for each loop works.
Do this and see if you can figure out the problem

```
   for(int i: nums){
     System.out.println(i);
   }
```

Comment: I like this kind of answers that make people understand rather than copy and paste.

Answer (score 3):

When you use it the "new way" you don't need to access the array anymore, you already have the reference of each item inside the loop.

```
public int arrayCount9(int[] nums) {
  int b=0;
   for(int i: nums){
     if(i == 9) b++;
   }
  return b;
}
```